# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add numbers from 0-99 to myData function so it prints all of my users with one click. But I'm getting an error.

> Error: *index.js:14 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
>       at index.js:14*

```
function number() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        i;
    }
}

const myData = () =>  {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?fbclid=IwAR2aHkMfSVPYV3va38MKu-jOahl9G8UzyPJ1Dd67EyskMPZMw1gN9xi-AUg')
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(users => {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += `
        User ID: ${users[number()].userId}<Br> 
        ID: ${users[number()].id}<br> 
        Title: ${users[number()].title}<Br>
        Desc: ${users[number()].body}`;
    })
}
```

Comment: `number` doesn't return anything, so `users[number()]` results in `users[undefined]`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added a `return i;` but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you hope the `number()` function will do. As you have it in the question it will run the for-loop then exit the function with a return value of `undefined`. Adding `return i` will cause it to return zero and exit the loop immediately.

If your intent is to set the `demo` id's innerHTML to have all users, then you need to have the actions within the loop like this:

```
.then(users => {
  let allUsersHtml = "";
  for (let i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
    allUsersHtml += `
    User ID: ${users[i].userId}<br> 
    ID: ${users[i].id}<br> 
    Title: ${users[i].title}<br>
    Desc: ${users[i].body}`;
  }
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = allUsersHtml;
})
```

This assumes that the `users` data coming back is an `Array` object.

The main problem with your first attempt is in understanding how functions operate. They can only return one thing each time they are called. Just because they include a for-loop doesn't mean they'll cause any repeating in the functions that call them.